# spark-sklearn, module object has not attribute '_fit_and_score'

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I'm experimenting with spark-sklearn and have the following code:

```
import os
import sys

# Path for spark source folder
os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="[spark folder location]"

# Append pyspark  to Python Path
sys.path.append("[spark's python folder location]")

from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext()

from sklearn import svm, grid_search, datasets
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV

iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svr = svm.SVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(sc, svr, parameters)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

And this results in the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[spark's python folder location]/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
File "[spark's python folder location]/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "[spark's python folder location]/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fit_and_score'

at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init> (PythonRDD.scala:207)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
... 1 more

16/02/26 09:35:53 INFO Executor: Executor killed task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5)
16/02/26 09:35:53 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, localhost): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)
16/02/26 09:35:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on executor localhost: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException (Traceback (most recent call last):
File "[spark's python folder location]/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
File "[spark's python folder location]/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
return self.loads(obj)
File "[spark's python folder location]/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 422, in loads
return pickle.loads(obj)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_fit_and_score')
```

I'm running ubuntu 14.04. I have spark-sklearn, and sklearn on my python path, and have installed python-sklearn via the ubuntu repositories. Spark 1.6 standalone works and I have called "pure" spark methods with success in python scripts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Spark-sklearn is fairly new so there's not a ton of information out.

Thanks

Comment: Do you run in local mode? If not could you provide some details about configuration. If yes, do you use any custom Python configuration?

Comment: I am running in local mode, yes. Not using any custom Python configuration.